# iOs: how to take into account all notification received when app become active

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm setting up Apple push notification for my iOS app.
If several notification are received when the app is not running (or in background), how can all received notifications be taken into account when the app (re)starts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 5 the push notifications accumulate in the tray.

In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
use UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey. This will give you the notification dictionary.

May be this can help you -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I'm using but it only takes the last one. Hmm... I should have missed something then. Thanks for your help, I'll check this once again.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But if you are programming for iOS 5 then the notifications accumulate in the tray. Whichever notification is tapped on will be received inside your application

Comment: only if in background, not if it really stopped ?

Comment: If your app is active or in background you receive the notifications in application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:

If your app was killed (or stopped) you receive it in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of getting push notifications programmatically.

The only way to handle these notifications is to implement `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` which will contain data about the notification that the user tapped.

The good way to achieve what you want is to have a web service of your own that you call when your application enters foreground.

Comment: thanks, this is what i'm doing but when the app is launched I though it should be possible to get all the notifications instead of just the last one.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way of doing that.